# What is the range of error [FANN]?

Tags: python, c++, fann

I use library FANN http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_cpp-h.html. The values of ANN:

i)activation_function_hidden: SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC_STEPWISE
ii)activation_function_output: LINEAR

My ANN(Artificial neural network), range of input: [0 - 10000]
Range or output: [0-26]

But the error sometimes is > 1.0, is it possible?, What is the range of error?

*Error in training

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually the mean square error. For each input record, fann calculates the difference between the target value and the observed value, squares it, sums them all together and divides through by the number of records. It is not a ratio or anything, so values larger than one are possible, particularly if your output values are larger than one.

I would try normalising your input so that it falls in the `[-1, 1]` range. Neural networks tend to like that more than a range of 0 to 10000.